# Regular Expression negate whole regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I want to parse this String with a regular expression into groups:

```
{4: :35B:ISIN DE000XXXXXXX DISC.Z 11.11.11 XXXX90 1234 (HSBC T R.? B.) /F:12345/R:N/W:N/C:N/S:N/G:N/A:N/F:N /XX/Any Word :16S:CONFDET :16R:SETDET :22F::SETR//TRAD :11A::FXIB//EUR :16R:AMT :19A::DEAL//EUR222, :16S:AMT :16R:AMT :19A::LOCO//EUR555 :16S:AMT :16R:AMT :19A::OTHR//EUR444 :16S:AMT :16R:AMT :19A::SETT//EUR333,33 :16S:AMT :16S:SETDET -}
```

I created this regex `(:\d\d[a-zA-Z]:*(\w*\/\/)?|:\d\d:)([^:]+)`
It matches in most of the cases, but not in this one. 
I want to extract Groups like this:

```
:35B: => ISIN DE000XXXXXXX DISC.Z 11.11.11 XXXX90 1234 (XXXX T R.? B.) /F:12345/R:N/W:N/C:N/S:N/G:N/A:N/F:N /XX/Any Word

:16S: => CONFDET

:16R: => SETDET
```

...

I expected that there is no ':' in the second group. Maybe someone can help me. I need to extact the whole Sting until the next :\d\d\w: Block.

Edit: The input String has a key-value Structure. For example :35B: is the key and everything behind until the next key is the value (in the case of the example the value is 'ISIN DE000XXXXXXX DISC.Z 11.11.11 XXXX90 1234 (XXXX T R.? B.) /F:12345/R:N/W:N/C:N/S:N/G:N/A:N/F:N /XX/Any Word').
I want to extract the key-value pairs of the input string. Here is a small code example of what i want:

```
CharSequence swiftMessage = "{4: :35B:ISIN DE000XXXXXXX DISC.Z 11.11.11 XXXX90 1234 (HSBC T R.? B.) /F:12345/R:N/W:N/C:N/S:N/G:N/A:N/F:N /XX/Any Word :16S:CONFDET :16R:SETDET :22F::SETR//TRAD :11A::FXIB//EUR :16R:AMT :19A::DEAL//EUR222, :16S:AMT :16R:AMT :19A::LOCO//EUR555 :16S:AMT :16R:AMT :19A::OTHR//EUR444 :16S:AMT :16R:AMT :19A::SETT//EUR333,33 :16S:AMT :16S:SETDET -}";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(:\\d\\d([a-zA-Z]):*(\\w*//)?|:\\d\\d:)([^:]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(swiftMessage);

while( matcher.find() ) {
    String key = matcher.group(1);
    String value = matcher.group(4);

    System.out.println(key + "=>" + value);

}
```

Expected Output (the stucture is key=>value):

```
:35B:=>ISIN DE000XXXXXXX DISC.Z 11.11.11 XXXX90 1234 (HSBC T R.? B.) /F:12345/R:N/W:N/C:N/S:N/G:N/A:N/F:N /XX/Any Word
:16S:=>CONFDET 
:16R:=>SETDET 
:22F::SETR//=>TRAD 
:11A::FXIB//=>EUR 
:16R:=>AMT 
:19A::DEAL//=>EUR222, 
:16S:=>AMT 
:16R:=>AMT 
:19A::LOCO//=>EUR555 
:16S:=>AMT 
:16R:=>AMT 
:19A::OTHR//=>EUR444 
:16S:=>AMT 
:16R:=>AMT 
:19A::SETT//=>EUR333,33 
:16S:=>AMT 
:16S:=>SETDET -}
```

In my regex the value of the key :35B: is 'ISIN DE000XXXXXXX DISC.Z 11.11.11 XXXX90 1234 (HSBC T R.? B.) /F' because my regex looks for the next colon. The expexted value should be 'ISIN DE000XXXXXXX DISC.Z 11.11.11 XXXX90 1234 (HSBC T R.? B.) /F:12345/R:N/W:N/C:N/S:N/G:N/A:N/F:N /XX/Any Word'

Hopefully now it's better to understand.

Comment: Please explain the structure of the input you are trying to extract. That regex is non-trivial to understand, and the input is quite long: make this easy for [SO] to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to find tokens separated by `(space):` and then treat part before first `:` in each token as key and rest as value.

In that case you can try with

```
(?<key>(?<=\\s):\\d\\d[a-zA-Z]):(?<value>.*?)(?=\\s:|$)
```

which will try to

- find `:\\d\\d[a-zA-Z]` part which was preceded by space `(?<=\\s)` and put it into group named `key`
- find minimal (since `*?` quantifier is reluctant) set of characters until next `\\s:` or end of string will be found, and place this part in group named `value`.

So your code can look like

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<key>(?<=\\s):\\d\\d[a-zA-Z]):(?<value>.*?)(?=\\s:|$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(swiftMessage);
while( matcher.find() ) {
    String key = matcher.group("key");
    String value = matcher.group("value");

    System.out.println(key + "=>" + value);

}
```

---

Other approach could be simply splitting on `\\s:` to get your data in parts like

```
{4:
35B:ISIN DE000XXXXXXX DISC.Z 11.11.11 XXXX90 1234 (HSBC T R.? B.) /F:12345/R:N/W:N/C:N/S:N/G:N/A:N/F:N /XX/Any Word
16S:CONFDET
...
16S:SETDET -}
```

and then split again each part on `:` but with limited number of splits to `2` (so `"foo:bar:baz:".split(":",2)` becomes `["foo", "bar:baz"]`).

With this approach your code can look like

```
for (String token : swiftMessage.toString().split("\\s:")){
    //System.out.println(token);
    //lets ignore first `{4:` part
    //maybe like this
    if (token.length()<=3) continue;

    String[] key_value = token.split(":",2);
    System.out.println(":"+key_value[0]+"=>"+key_value[1]);
}
```